# How can I send file to django app from flutter?

Tags: django, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dio

I am trying to send a pptx file to a django server at this [link](https://nitemode.herokuapp.com/) from flutter

this is the html form which is in the original django app:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="find_file_type">
{% csrf_token %}
<div>
    <label class = "custom-file-upload" >
        Choose file
        <input name = "filePath" type="file" accept = ".pdf , application/vnd.ms-powerpoint , application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation" id="file">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Make it dark" id= "submit">
</div>

</form>
```

I am unable to send file to this server and have no idea what's wrong.
Here is what I'v tried using the dio package:

```
void sendRequest() async{
    FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
      "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path,filename: filename)});
    response = await dio.post("https://nitemode.herokuapp.com/find_file_type", data: formData);
    print(response);
    if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
      print('Uploaded!');
    }
    print("Process complete");

  }
}
```

Here is the output I'm getting:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error
 [403]
E/flutter (19891): #0      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio.dart:966:7)
E/flutter (19891): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19891): #1      DioMixin._request._interceptorWrapper.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:di
o/src/dio.dart:849:37)
E/flutter (19891): #2      DioMixin.checkIfNeedEnqueue (package:dio/src/dio.dart:1121:22)
E/flutter (19891): #3      DioMixin._request._interceptorWrapper.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio.dart:846:2
2)
E/flutter (19891): #4      new Future.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:174:37)
E/flutter (19891): #5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
E/flutter (19891): #6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (19891): #7      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter (19891): #8      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter (19891): #9      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter (19891): #10     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (19891): #11     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:23)
E/flutter (19891): #12     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter (19891): #13     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:397:19)
E/flutter (19891): #14     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:428:5)
E/flutter (19891): #15     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
E/flutter (19891):
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
The django app sends a download after a file has been uploaded, is that why I'm getting this error? Since the django app dosent send 200 or 203 response but a response like this:

```
response = HttpResponse(myfile, content_type='application/[vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation]')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='  + 'DarkFile.pptx'
```

Plz help me I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
I have read the documentation for dio too but no idea what I'm doing wrong
I have also tried the download() function in dio but no file gets downloaded.
I have also done a post() and a donwload() function together but that also does nothing.

Comment: https://dev.to/carminezacc/advanced-flutter-networking-part-1-uploading-a-file-to-a-rest-api-from-flutter-using-a-multi-part-form-data-post-request-2ekm

check above to see http.MultipartFile, hopes it will help